# Is it possible to generate a struct with a macro?

Tags: rust

```
trait Print {
    fn print(&self);
}
struct Printer {
    p: Box<Print>,
}
fn main() {
    let i = 1i32;
    let s = String::from_str("Hello");

    // let mp = make_printer!(i,s);
    let mp = |i: i32, s: String| {
        struct Foo {
            i: i32,
            s: String,
        }
        impl Foo {
            fn new(i: i32, s: String) -> Foo {
                Foo { i: i, s: s }
            }
        }
        impl Print for Foo {
            fn print(&self) {
                println!("{} {}", self.i, self.s);
            }
        }
        Printer { p: box Foo::new(i, s) }
    };

    let printer = mp(i, s);
    printer.p.print();
}
```

I want to create the `make_printer!` macro which should expand to `mp` if I call it with `make_printer!(i,s)`.

Is this is possible? I think the biggest issue here is that I need something like `decltype` from C++ so that I can extract the type from a variable. The struct could then look like:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]
macro_rules! make_printer(
    ($($element:ident),*) => (
        struct Foo{
            $($element : decltype($element),)*
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: So we have some state, plus a method to operate on that state. And it needs to work on any type and number of types, and should be easy to build on the fly by the looks of it. That sounds like a job for closures.

Comment: @A.B. I am not sure if we can build closures on the fly at the moment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do it with just the expression identifiers. You need explicit types, e.g.

```
macro_rules! make_printer {
    ($($element: ident: $ty: ty),*) => {
        struct Foo { $($element: $ty),* }
    }
}
```

called like `make_printer!(x: i32, y: String)`.

This is required for two, mostly orthogonal, reasons:

- macros don't have access to any type information, they are just local syntactic transformations (e.g. it's not even possible to write a macro (either `macro_rules!` or procedural) that can tell if a given `ident` refers to a local variable).
- Rust doesn't have a `decltype` equivalent.