# Best way to populate a struct from a similar struct?

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers, prost

I am new to Rust, and am attempting to take a struct returned from a library (referred to as source struct) and convert it into protobuf message using `prost`. The goal is to take the source struct, map the source struct types to the protobuf message types (or rather, the appropriate types for prost-generated struct, referred to as message struct), and populate the message struct fields using fields from the source struct. The source struct fields are a subset of message struct fields. For example:

```rust
pub struct Message {
    pub id: i32,
    pub email: String,
    pub name: String,
}

pub struct Source {
    pub email: Email,
    pub name: Name,
}
```

So, I would like to take fields from from `Source`, map the types to corresponding types in `Message`, and populate the fields of `Message` using `Source` (fields have the same name). Currently, I am manually assigning the values by creating a `Message` struct and doing something like `message_struct.email = source_struct.email.to_string();`. Except I have multiple Message structs based on protobuf, some having 20+ fields, so I'm really hoping to find a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Please provide your existing conversion code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to generate define new struct based on fields from another. In that case you have to use `macros`.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html

Also this question (and answer) could be useful for you [Is it possible to generate a struct with a macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25217988/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-struct-with-a-macro)

To convert struct values from one to another struct best way is to use `From<T>` or `Into<T>` trait.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html

Answer (score 5):

This is called FRU (functional record update).
This currently works only for structs with the same type and structs with the same type modulo generic parameters.

The [RFC-2528](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2528-type-changing-struct-update-syntax.md#further-generalization) talks about a generalization that would make this work:

```rust
struct Foo {
    field1: &'static str,
    field2: i32,
}

struct Bar {
    field1: f64,
    field2: i32,
}

let foo = Foo { field1: "hi", field2: 1 };
let bar = Bar { field1: 3.14, ..foo };
```

Unfortunately, this has not yet been implemented.

Comment: The RFC mentions that as an _alternative_. The proposed method in the RFC is to only allow the same struct.

Answer (score 4):

You could make a method to create a `Message` from a `Source` like this.

```
impl Message {
    pub fn from_source(source: &Source, id: i32) -> Self {
        Message {
            id: id,
            email: source.email.to_string(),
            name: source.name.to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

And then,

```
let source = // todo
let id = // todo
let message = Message::from_source(&source, id);
```